# Is there a callback for DialogFragment when it is shown?

Tags: android

`Dialog` in Android has an interface: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnShowListener

Is there a counterpart for `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` in Android?

Comment: Remember that DialogFragment is deprecated in API level 28. However, it extends Fragment, so you could use OnResume()

Comment: @BruceWayne It refers to the `DialogFragment` in support library.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a the documation here -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html

onStart() - Called when the Fragment is visible to the user.

I think it is the closest callback you will find...

Comment: The implementation of `DialogFragment.onStart()` is simply calling `mDialog.show()` which is prior to the exact moment when the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `DialogFragment` extends from `Fragment`, which is `LifeCycleAware` component.
So, if you want to know, when DialogFramgnet is shown, you can use `LifecycleObserver`:

```
private void showTestDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog1 = new DialogFragment();
        dialog1.getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyObserver());
        dialog1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
    }

    private class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
        void connectListener() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: one probably should first add the observer and then show it, else it will be shown without observation. it does not match the [use cases](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#use-cases) and [Lifecycle.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html) `ON_RESUME` is the `onResume` of the `LifecyleOwner`.

Answer (score 0):

Override methods [.onAttach()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) or [.onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)). Or `Fragment` [.onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: But these are methods invoked prior to the exact moment when a dialog is shown, right? I am looking for a callback for that moment.